# Recursively Reverse Several User Inputs in C

Tags: c, recursion

I was wondering whether there is a way besides using arrays, arrayLists, linkedLists in C to reverse some user input.

For example, if the user enters a certain amount of numbers, and ends their entry with a 10, can these numbers be reversed using recursion rather than multi-element data structures?

For example,

4
5
6
7
10

becomes

7
6
5
4

And guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rec_f(void){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n != 10){
        rec_f();
        printf("%d ", n);
    }
}

int main(){
    rec_f();
    return 0;
}
```